# keycloak Profile SPI

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am looking for Profile SPI in keycloak admin panel but can't seems to find it. As described in this [link](http://blog.keycloak.org/2016/12/keycloak-250cr1-released.html)  Keycloak 3 will have this feature. 
My main aim is to add some custom user attributes and Validate them. But I found from this [link](https://github.com/cfpb/hmda-platform-auth/issues/42) it is not possible to add custom validator for user management and profile update page. Is it still valid for Keycloak 4.5.0.final version?